# Codeigniter 3 use of db->like for multiple columns results in an SQL related error

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sql-like, query-builder

I am working on a basic **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8.

The **search posts** functionality gives me unexpected trouble:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* LIKE '%expression%' ESCAPE '!'' at line 3

SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE * LIKE '%expression%' ESCAPE '!'
```

The `search()` method in the Posts model looks like this:

```
public function search($expression) {
    $this->db->like('*', $expression);
    $query = $this->db->get('posts');
    return $query->result();
}
```

The relevant table fields are:

[image]

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `$this->db->like('*', $expression);` what is * ?

Comment: @sagi it is *all columns*

Comment: This is not possible in SQL. * is used in select list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new CodeIgniter release (*3.1.9*), there was a fix for an unwanted typo ... Inside `system/database/DB_query_builder.php` at line **#973** I believe:

This :

`case 'before':
    $v = "%'{$v}'"; // <- Check here
    break;`

Was changed to this:

`case 'before':
    $v = "'%{$v}'"; // <- The fix
    break;`

Try to do this change and see if this fixes your issue or not.

**EDITED**

After seeing your code, please don't use `*` as a field name, you have to specify what field is used for the search ... For instance, if you want to search in titles, descriptions and contents, you may proceed as this:

```
$query = $this->db->like('title', $expression)
              ->or_like('description', $expression)
              ->or_like('content', $expression);
```

Then the rest of your code. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use column/expression instead of `*`:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE * LIKE '%expression%' ESCAPE '!'
=>
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE column_name LIKE '%expression%' ESCAPE '!';
```

---

> *I need to seelct from all columns in the posts table*

Then you could use something like(be aware of poor performance because `CONCAT` and `LIKE '%exp'` make it nonSARGable.

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` 
WHERE CONCAT(col1,col2, col3, ...)  LIKE '%expression%' ESCAPE '!'
```

To avoid potential problems with `CONCAT` you should add separator:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` 
WHERE CONCAT(col1,'^',col2,'^',col3, ...)  LIKE '%expression%' ESCAPE '!'
```

Comment: I need to seelct from *all columns* in the posts table

Comment: @sagi Then he needs to  add separator that is unlikely to exist in any column. I will update my answer.

Comment: Also, I would like a Codeigniter specific solution.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir Sorry, I don't know PHP. I am sure it is possible to translate expression `CONCAT(col1,'^',col2,'^',col3, ...)` to your ORM. As last resort you could always execute native query.